# .jar executable file that stays "small window"

Tags: java

here is my problem. 
There is a .jar executable file that I try to launch (on W10) using the command line javaw.exe -java "C:\thefile.jar" and I can see a small window opened using alt+tab, but it's impossible to select it/make it the main window.
I have never seen such a thing before. The file (a chess program) is used by several people and it seems that I am the only one dummy that can't use it :( 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you’re the only one that can’t use it, ask someone who can what they did :)

Comment: that's not possible unfortunately

Comment: A quick google suggests there might be issues with jar files on windows 10, but I didn’t read them, so maybe have a look around, or try on an earlier version of windows.

Comment: Try running it with `java.exe` rather than `javaw.exe`.  If it's printing error messages, you'll get to see them and might get a clue.  Perhaps some resources are missing on your system, or you're using the wrong version of Java.